# How to configure a multi-module Apache Maven project to use a Checkstyle config project that consists of multiple XML files that reference each other?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I would like to configure the [Apache Maven Checkstyle Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin) v3.3.0 with [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) v3.9.3 in a multi-module project to use the [palantir-java-format](https://github.com/palantir/palantir-java-format) style.

I've read both [Multimodule Configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) and [Using Custom Developed Checkstyle Checks](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-developed-checkstyle.html) of the official plugin documentation. As recommended in the documentation I created a separate `jar` Maven project `example-company-config`. The single purpose of `example-company-config` is to provide the Checkstyle config files as resources in a JAR file. B ydoing that the Checkstyle config can be shared across many Maven projects.

- I was able to make it work with a standalone (i.e. no references to other XML files) `checkstyle.xml` file.
- **But** here is the problem: The [palantir-java-format Checkstyle config](https://github.com/palantir/palantir-java-format/tree/f354703a0b7057255f4740db99377a64e4ddc823/.baseline/checkstyle) uses three files and the `checkstyle.xml` references the other files with a property `config_loc`.

I found out how to to set that property. The following is a snippet of my Aggregator POM.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.github.florianwolters</groupId>
                        <artifactId>example-company-config</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                    <configLocation>io.github.florianwolters/checkstyle/palantir/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <propertyExpansion>config_loc=.</propertyExpansion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
<build>
```

**But:** Since all three Checkstyle files of palantir-java-format are stored inside the JAR file of the `example-company-config` project, this does not work.

I identified three possible solutions:

1. Qualify a XML file from another XML file inside the same archive file with a "special syntax". I don't think that this syntax exists and therefore that this is not possible.
2. Extract the JAR file of `example-company-config` during the build process and reference to it using an absolute file path.

   Maybe this is possible with the [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin).
3. Turn the `example-company-config` from type `jar` to type `pom` and install the Checkstyle config files manually.

   Maybe this is possible with the [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin).

Notes:

- I consider modification of the three Checkstyle config files a non-solution.
- I'm aware that the [Spotless for Maven](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven) plugin exists. I do not want to fail the build (yet) in case of formatting violations. Therefore I want to use the palantir-java-format style with the Checkstyle tool. I may migrate from Checkstyle to Spotless later.

Do you have a solution or some guidance for the problem I've described?

Related resources:

- [how to externalise the checkstyle config for maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19682455/891439)
- [Can't configure Checkstyle in Maven multimodule project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32436495/891439)
- [Maven - Dependency on module for Checkstyle not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46211370/891439)
- [How To: Wie man in Maven seine Checkstyle-Konfiguration zentral verwaltet](https://senacor.blog/how-to-wie-man-in-maven-seine-checkstyle-konfiguration-zentral-verwaltet)

Comment: The `<configLocation>` parameter specifies the location of the XML configuration file. In your snippet, the parameter does not seem to specify a file. Is there a typo?

Comment: @ChinHuang Yes, that was indeed a typo. Thanks for your comment. Btw, I found a solution to my problem (using the Apache Maven Dependency Plugin). I may add an extensive answer later.

Comment: Does it work if you set `<propertyExpansion>config_loc=io.github.florianwolters/checkstyle/palantir</propertyExpansion>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this on my own, by utilizing the [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin).

The following excerpt from my `pom.xml` for the Company POM project should contain all the relevant stuff to make this work. Note that the Company POM uses the `example-checkstyle-config` project as recommended by the documentation linked in the OP. The JAR file of the separate `example-checkstyle-config` project is extracted during the build of all child projects (note that the Company POM itself has to be exclude, otherwise I'd have a cyclic dependency (in addition its useless work, because a Company POM does not have source code).

By doing all this this an absolute file path can be injected via the `<propertyExpansion>` element and everything works as expected.

**But:** I had to modify the [palantir-java-format Checkstyle config](https://github.com/palantir/palantir-java-format/tree/f354703a0b7057255f4740db99377a64e4ddc823/.baseline/checkstyle):

1. The `custom-suppressions.xml` file suppresses all warnings.
2. The `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` files suppresses warnings in test files. I'd like to have warnings for all source files.

Therefore, my requirements in the OP was not met. Nonetheless, do I think, that I've found a neat solution for the problem (and similar problems that can be solved by "simply" extracting a dependency to the own build tree directory).

```
<properties>
    <io.github.florianwolters.build.unpackDirectory>${project.build.directory}/unpack</io.github.florianwolters.build.unpackDirectory>
    <io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.unpackDirectory>${io.github.florianwolters.build.unpackDirectory}/checkstyle-config</io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.unpackDirectory>
    <io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.configDirectory>${io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.unpackDirectory}/${project.groupId}/checkstyle/palantir</io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.configDirectory>

    <io.github.florianwolters.version.company-checkstyle-config>0.1.0</io.github.florianwolters.version.company-checkstyle-config>
    <io.github.florianwolters.version.maven-checkstyle-plugin>3.3.0</io.github.florianwolters.version.maven-checkstyle-plugin>
    <io.github.florianwolters.version.checkstyle>10.12.1</io.github.florianwolters.version.checkstyle>
</properties>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.maven-checkstyle-plugin}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.checkstyle}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>example-checkstyle-config</artifactId>
                        <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.company-checkstyle-config}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.configDirectory}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <enableFilesSummary>true</enableFilesSummary>
                    <enableRulesSummary>true</enableRulesSummary>
                    <enableSeveritySummary>true</enableSeveritySummary>
                    <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                    <propertyExpansion>config_loc=${io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.configDirectory}</propertyExpansion>
                    <skip>${checkstyle.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.maven-dependency-plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>dependency.unpack.company-checkstyle-config</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>example-checkstyle-config</artifactId>
                                    <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.company-checkstyle-config}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${io.github.florianwolters.checkstyle.unpackDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <!-- Skip the execution for the parent Maven project. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>dependency.unpack.company-checkstyle-config</id>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: Why not using the documented solution for multi module builds https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I've used that. Please refer to the 1st link (it's the same link provided by you) in the 2nd paragraph in the OP. The question was not about the "basics", but about the usage of variables (to reference other files) in the `checkstyle.xml` and injection of custom properties via the `propertyExpansion` attribute. This answer provides only the part that deals with these details. The "basics" are already covered in the link you've also posted. In other words: The official documentation could be extended with this answer for "advanced" usage, not the other way around.